# asterisk dial hangup direction - Is there a variable I can use to record the direction of hangup?

Tags: asterisk

Is there a variable I can use to record the direction of hangup?

Example: Calling ----> Called. Called party hangs up. Info I want --> Release from Called party

Example 2: Calling ----> Called. Caller hangs up. Info I want --> Release from Calling party

Comment: in **AMI** there is an *event* called `Hangup` where you can identify the *channel* that hangs up.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dial command with 'g' option, if CALLED hangup you will go to next priority after dialled

If CALLER hangup you will go 'h' extension in same context, but you will be NOT able say something to caller.